# VBA excel: How do I compare a string array to a string?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script that takes the contents of a cell, and puts the first 2 characters of the cell into a string array. I need to later compare that string array to a string, but I can't seem to get that to work. Here's what I have:

```
For i = 2 To 600
colStr = Sheets("smartlist").Cells(i, "A").Value
If colStr <> "" Then
    ReDim charArray(Len(colStr) - 1)
    For j = 1 To Len(colStr)
        charArray(j - 1) = Mid$(colStr, j, 1)
    Next
    strArray = LCase(charArray(0)) & LCase(charArray(1))

    If CStr(Join(strArray)) = CStr(Join(pwArray)) Then
```

Now, I've tried:

```
If charArray = "ab"

If Join(charArray) = "ab"

If CStr(Join(charArray)) = "ab"
```

I'm pretty lost at this point. Any suggestions would be welcome!

Edit: added the whole function up until I get the 'Type mismatch'

Comment: You loop with the var i but use j to index your array in the for loop -> is this a typo or where does j come from?

Comment: @DAXaholic typo when I moved it over, fixed. When I debug, I can see that charArray looks to be correctly holding the values in the cells, it's the comparison I'm having issues with.

Comment: Just to be sure that I understood it correctly: you want to check if "ab" is one of the elements of the array?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand why you're doing this. Why not use spreadsheet formulas? You could cut a lot of the coding work by using formulas then grind the data with VBA later.

Comment: @DAXaholic I want to check if the letters combined make "ab" i.e. charArray(0) is "a", and charArray(1) is "b"

Comment: Also, If your array contains the first *two* characters of your cell, you're only testing the *first character* using `Mid$(colStr, i, 1)`.

Comment: Can you post all of the code for this function, please?

Comment: @Paul how so? I'm not very familiar with vba or excel...

Comment: Can you clarify what is contained in `charArray` and where the string comes from (`colStr`).

Comment: @Paul posted all of it up until I get the error on type mismatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you really need to clarify what you're doing. You say that *later* you need to check what's in the string. If that is the case, then you don't need an array, you simply need another string...

```
Dim chars As String
chars = Left$(cellToTest, 2)
```

Later you can test more simply using the `InStr` function, like so...

```
Dim loc As Integer
loc = Instr(colStr, chars)
If loc > 0 Then
    ...
```

If you want to turn this into a function on your spreadsheet you can use the following in the cells as formulas...

```
=LEFT(A1, 2)
=SEARCH(A3, A1)
```

Here's a little screen shot of what I mean...

[image: Formula usage]

Comment: By 'later' I was referring to the comparison further down in the code, but this is EXACTLY what I needed, thank you!

Comment: No problem, Chuck. Despite the fact that it's not brilliant, the help (F1) with formulas in Excel may be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Join(charArray, "")` - without "" it joins the elements with space so the result of your initial try was "a b"